# Evaluation and Validation with Java

Tags: java

I want to validate my application with two keys on installation by trial and permanent,
on trial key I want to give a validation check of 30 days. I used some way but could not get find feather and need help or link.

Comment: I'm familiar with the subject, but am baffled as to what "find feather" is. Could you elaborate on this so we can provide a meaningful answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One common pitfall with trial-based keys is you can simply turn back the clock on your computer to the time you installed it for another 30 days. There are a couple ways around this.

1. Limit the trial to the expected number of program-actions (saves, loads, etc) you'd get in 30 days.
2. Limit the trial to a reasonable number of program-openings (how many times the program was actually opened.)
3. Require an internet connection and validate the trial is still within 30 days on your own server. (Drop the connection requirement when they go full. Phoning home is generally frowned upon, especially for fully owned applications.)

Comment: The trial period for my favourite graphical diff program is 30 days of use rather than 30 days from installation date.  That's a nice way to do it imo.